# Link from wicket grid control

Tags: datagrid, popupwindow

I am using a grid created in Apache Wicket. In the cells of one of the columns I have an icon. When that icon is clicked a pop up should be created showing data for that row. How should this be implemented so that the pop up is created and populated ONLY IF the user clicks on an icon? Can I link from the grid cell directly to java code where the pop up will be created?